Scala slick 3.3.x combining filterOpt with OR
I am having two option seq strings in scala:
val firstSeq = Some(Seq("1", "2", "3"))
val secondSeq = Some(Seq("car", dog", "cat"))

I am querying data in oracle db with slick query:
(for {
  number <- numbers
    .filterOpt(firstSeq)((table, gs) => table.count.inSetBind(gs) && table.type === NumberType.Numeric)
    .filterOpt(secondSeq)((table, rs) => table.count.inSetBind(rs) && table.type === NumberType.String)
} yield {
  number
}).result

Is there a way how to combine these two filterOpt methods into one with OR condition ?

what's the query you want to produce? what should happen if one of the Seq is None? what if both are None? I would guess that numbers is of type TableQuery[Numbers] or similar. Could you edit your post and show the definition of numbers? same with the schema you are mapping to the table. Is it possible to share a minimal reproducible example?

based on the scaladoc of filterOpt method
  /** Applies the given filter, if the Option value is defined.
    * If the value is None, the filter will not be part of the query. */

the condition will be added to the query only if the Option passed as parameter is a Some. In this case, you have two Seqs. One possible solution could be to define a case class to contain both collections and then pass it to the filterOpt wrapped inside an Option. You could also define a Tuple instead of a case class.
case class BothSeqs(first: Seq[Int], second: Seq[String])

val firstSeq = Seq("1", "2", "3")
val secondSeq = Seq("car", "dog", "cat")

val bothSeqs = BothSeqs(firstSeq, secondSeq)

numbers
  .filterOpt(Some(bothSeqs))((table,seqs) => 
      (table.count.inSetBind(seqs.first) && table.type === NumberType.Numeric)
        || (table.count.inSetBind(seqs.second) && table.type === NumberType.String)
  )

